# PHP ARRAY search key and apply action

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array which contains values like this

See below for script sample

Suppose this is in a variable $Output_Data

I want to apply certain function on this $Output_Data listed below

1. Remove Duplicate VALUE also associating KEY (but must keep one)
   i know this can be achieved by function array_unique but how to delete the array key
2. If img exist than put it in a variable adding img tag example

   ```
   if exist img key in output data (or flv or mp4)
       $output_img[] = '<a href="$Output_Data[img]">Image "$i"</a>';
   ```

   Like this for every key i mean FLV, MP4, IMG
3. Output to user screen Now again we created new Array separating the data

   ```
   $output_img[] 
   $output_flv[] 
   $output_mp4[]
   ```

So if the array contains data than output it to user screen...(here also check if they exist or empty)

I am not a pro in this thing i just want to add a feature to my website and i hate array a lot  but it is the only thing that will help me.

You can also mention a Alternative Solution for this... Because it is just my thought not a Necessity.

Sorry for wrong code here is a sample script

```
function sortoutput($data_to_sort,$key_explode_char) {   
 $output_content = array();
    foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $data_to_sort) as $cLine) { 
        list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode($key_explode_char, $cLine, 2); 
        $output_content[$cKey] = $cValue;
    }
    return $output_content;
    }
                    ob_start();
                            $flv = 'http://example.com/example.flv';
                            $flv2 = 'http://example.com/example2.flv';
                             $img = 'http://example.com/my.jpg';
                            $mp4 = 'http://example.com/okay.mp4';
                            print 'flv=`'.$flv.PHP_EOL;
                            print 'flv=`'.$flv2.PHP_EOL;
                            print 'img=`'.$img.PHP_EOL;
                            print 'mp4=`'.$mp4;
                            $Output_Download_Link = ob_get_contents();
                             ob_end_clean();


                            echo $Output_Download_Link;
                            $Sorted_Output_Links = sortoutput($Output_Download_Link, '=`');

                             echo '<pre>';
                            print_r($Sorted_Output_Links);
                            echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The above array is not possible. You cannot have the same key multiple times. Please post your actual array (using `var_export` is preferred).

Comment: Try printing your array with `print_r` or `var_dump`, and wrap the output in `<pre>` tags. You'll find that you do not have the structure you think you have.

Comment: just posted teh new code in below please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch keys and values. A key is always unique! You can't have two or more entries with the same key name (except using a 2-dimensional array...).

After this you can get the keys of an array with array_keys() and use array_unique()

```
$array = array('url1' => 'flv', 'url2' => 'flv', 'url3' => 'png');
$keys = array_keys($array); //all urls
$keys = array_unique($keys); //remove url duplicates
$output = array( //all extensions which should be stored in array
    'flv' => array(),
    'png' => array(),
    'mp4' => array(),
);

foreach($keys as $url) {
    $extension = $array[$url];
    if(isset($output[$extension])) {
        $id = count($output[$extension]) + 1;
        $output[$extension][] = "<a href=\"".$url."\">Image #".$id."</a>";
    }
}

foreach($output as $o) {
    //Output all arrays which aren't empty
    if(!empty($o)) {
        $o = implode('', $o);
        echo $o.'<hr />';
    }
}
```

A better way would be if you get the extension from the link directly using substr() and strrpos().

Than you can check whether $output[$extension] exists and create first an empty array() on $output[$extension]. This way you are more flexible with the extensions...

**Edit:** After you added a correct example...

You have to change this line: $output_content[$cKey] = $cValue;

```
//OLD: $output_content[$cKey] = $cValue;
//NEW:
if(!isset($output_content[$cKey])) {
    $output_content[$cKey] = array();
}
$output_content[$cKey][] = "<a href=\"".$cValue."\">".$cValue."</a>";
```

And then you can check every entry of $output_content whether it is empty or not and output it. (have a look at the my first example above)

Comment: Sorry the code i Posted was a Mistake i am changing it i just thought abt it but when i tested i got to know that i don't get double key...

Comment: @Ispcity I am little confused. The thing u did is very good but it doesn't complete my purpose. Just few things remaining.. 1)Like u applied the a tag to them can we also add a Img tag But according to the Key like [flv]=>[0]=><a href="><img src='0.gif'></a> [flv]=>[1]=><a href="><img src='1.gif'>.....Also you example code the 2d array is not working in my case. i mean than how to output by checking if the 0 1 2 (sub sub key) etc and how many of it exists...

Comment: Also one thing more thing is that the extension thing is waste of time because the links of mp4 and flv will have an authentication code rather than extension. We are already making section as per ur suggestion. So how to count how many key exist in flv img or mp4 and also if value exist or not.

Comment: First $output_content is empty. So if you add a link there will be created a sub-array: $output_content['flv']. In this sub-array you have at least one entry (otherwise it wouldn't exist). Now my code above adds more entries to this sub-array if the extension exists more than one time. After adding all entries your array could look like this: $output_content['flv'] = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3',...). You can call the entries with $output_content['flv'][0] or $output_content['flv'][1] or ... Therefore you can use my foreach, remove the empty-check and implode() the content. This should work

Comment: For your other information: When asking something here you should "all relevant" and important information into your question post while you create the question. If there are more information given along with one entry you have to write it. You cannot expect that people can help you when you give information in pieces and only if the current answers are not satisfying. Think about the code and play and try a little bit with it.

Comment: @Ispcity I am sorry u are really helping a lot i tried to work with it yesterday but was not getting result.. as per u 'Therefore you can use my foreach, remove the empty-check and implode() the content. This should work' here i am stuck every thing is looking and working great just the end part is not working for me..The example you provided of $array contains only 1 key but in our example we have two keys.. i have weak knowledge in arrays and foreach so i m very dependent on u sir.

Comment: Hello sorry again sir i got it... Thank you very much for helping :)...and sorry again for the trouble caused... I was actually confusing between for and foreach.. i read a tutorial http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-array.html?page=3 and got to know it.. i was looking at ur code and didn